# Simulate build provider in ASP.NET Web Application (.Net 2.0)

Tags: .net, asp.net

I am working with .Net 2.0 ASP.NET Web Application.

I am programmatically creating an assembly containing namespace and classes specified within xml file in the web application.
I have created a separate library that does that, I get the assembly and that's fine.

But I don't want to reference this as a precompiled component.

I want to create it on the fly, so when I run the build of the web application, the assembly is built, the reference to the assembly added and then the web application code can use it further. Plus, I can have the intellisense.

Now this is exactly the scenario for the build providers, but the problem is that the build providers don't work with this type of application.

I have managed to run the assembly generation tool like so:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Exec Command="CreateAssembly.exe config.xml"/>
</Target>
```

But no luck with dynamically referencing the generated assembly..

Answer (score 1):

The class you are looking for is the Assembly class within the System.Reflection namespace.

### Example

```
Assembly.Load(AssemblyPath)
```

or

```
Assembly.LoadFrom(AssemblyPath)
```

These methods can be used to load a non-referenced assembly into your app-domain.

There are various conditions and restrictions so I would read up on them both.

### Links

[Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx) (MSDN)

[Assembly.LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom.aspx) (MSDN)

[Useful MS KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837908)

Have fun!

Comment: Charles, thanks, I'm aware of the System.Reflection, but I'm looking for a way to reference it within build process.

Answer (score 0):

I've been toying around with using Rake for automating builds recently so you might want to give that a try. Here's a couple of links that you might find useful:

- http://www.tobinharris.com/2008/11/4/getting-started-with-rake-on-net
- http://www.tobinharris.com/2008/12/13/automate-boring-tasks-with-rake-in-dotnet

Comment: Thanks Ian, seems really interesting - nice syntax for a build runner. :) I'll look if it could provide the means for my needs.